# Get index of selected tab in tabHost

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-tabhost

I'm trying to store the index of the currently selected tab in onSaveInstanceState so I can restore it. However the getCurrentTab apparantely gives me back the String I used in the etTabHost().newTabSpec, which I find a bit weird since the documentation says it returns an int and setCurrentTab also taking an int.
Does anyone know how I can get the index of my currently selected tab so I can restore it?

Comment: Are you sure that you invoke the TabHost.getCurrentTab()? It returns int. Probably you misplaced that with getCurrentTabTag()?

Comment: I'm certain, that's why I find it so weird.

Comment: What android version do you use?

Comment: I select 2.2 google from the list, but I don't think I'm using any specific features.

Answer (score 26):

you are on the right way, use `setOnTabChangedListener` to get your selected tab.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    static TabHost mytabs;

    mytabs = getTabHost();
    mytabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         
            Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());
        }       
    });  
...
...
...
```

Comment: I currently don't have access to my laptop with the code so I'll have to try this tomorrow, but why would it make any difference whether I used getCurrentTab in the onTabChanged event or in my onSaveInstanceState?

And thank you for your current answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use getCurrentTab() that returns index of tab start from 0.

Comment: That method belongs to which object? `something.getCurrentTab()` and what is something?

Answer (score 2):

Use tabHost.getCurrentTab() to get Tab ...

```
tabHost= getTabHost();
tabHost.addTab(tab0); // TabSpec tab0=tabHost.newTabSpec(...
tabHost.addTab(tab1); //  TabSpec tab1=tabHost.newTabSpec

int current = tabHost.getTabHost() ;
```