# Refreshing/updating activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to refresh my activity. I have bunch of question regrading the same which advice me to finish current activity and restart the current activity. OR again provide value to each widget. To avoid transition I used this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
this.finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

But in my case In my activity I have four tabs, and I need to refresh all four tabs.

There are few more problems regarding the same 
1) With above code, if I am on other screen, I come back to this screen when above piece  of code runs.

2) Activity sequence gets disturb.

3) Maintaining selected tab will also be a part of problem

Even if I try to refresh each tab seperatley,  One of my tab have webview. how to refresh that as webview.loadData() can't be called unless there is view and since I am not on that tab there will no view.

What can be the ideal way to tackle this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was not much complicated but solution what I wanted got to be optimised. Finally I took the second way, ie refreshing each component. This approach overcomes the problem of disturbing the sequence of activity. For web view I am still using `webView.loadData(...)`.

In total I have handeled each tab separately. If I include my entire code then it would become clumsy, but still trying to incorporate as many important feature.

In my activity class when I need to refresh my activity, I called this method.

```
private void onRefrash()
{   
    refreshCurrentActivity();

    int selectedTab = getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex();
    switch (selectedTab)
    {
    case TAB1:
        fragment1.update();
        break;
    case TAB2:
        fragment2.update();
        break;
    case TAB3:
        fragment3.update();
        break;
    }       
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.msg_case_updates_received), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }                       
}
```

Each fragment is earlier initialised, and update method is called for each tab in which I am updating the corresponding web view.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your use case. You may setContentView() again to inflate the layout every time. If you are just displaying a list, then you may just call the adapter to display the list. You have to do this for every fragment in your TabActivity.

To reload a WebView I would just call [loadUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) again.

As to remembering the selected tab, you have to [store it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583405/get-index-of-selected-tab-in-tabhost) and then set the current tab in the [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html).

Comment: simple and precise. Thanks I will give it a try

Comment: Great, let us know how it goes!