# Get the index of touched tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I cannot get the indexe of touched tabhost on android
Can any one help me?
my problem is to get the indexe onTouch and not on Click

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `TabHost` fires the `onClick` event, and has an `onTabChangedListener` listener, have you tried that?

Comment: i would like to get the indexe of touched tabhost before selecte   int numberOfTabs = RMBTMainMenuFragment.mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
     for(t=0; t<numberOfTabs; t++){
      RMBTMainMenuFragment.mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

Comment: Still makes no sense. The touched tab will be the one that will be clicked, why not implement it in `onTabChangedListener`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
TabHost.getCurrentTab()
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#getCurrentTab%28%29)

**EDIT:** If you want to have a listener you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583405/get-index-of-selected-tab-in-tabhost).

Comment: thank you so much ,but my problem that i dont like to select the tabhost but only get the indexe when i touch the tabhost

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code.It will helpful for you

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.i("Tab changes", arg0);


        }
    });
```